# Redux not updating Component's props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've tried all of the related questions here in Stack Overflow and still didn't find a solution to this problem.

I have a reducer called `me` and I'm trying to update an array of objects in it called `folders`, whenever I update the `me` reducer the component doesn't update.

Here's how I'm updating the reducer in my component:

```
class ComponentA extends Component {
  ...
  updateUploadedFiles(file) {
    console.log(this.props.store);
    const newFolders = this.props.me.folders.map(
      folder =>
        folder._id === file.parent._id
          ? {
              ...folder,
              files: [...folder.files, file.file]
            }
          : folder
    );

    this.props.updateMe({
      ...this.props.me,
      folders: newFolders
    });
  }
  ...
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    me: state.me,
    path: state.path,
    filesToUpload: state.uploads
  };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      updatePath,
      updateMe,
      updateUploads
    },
    dispatch
  );
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps, null, {
  pure: false
})(Upload);
```

this is my `updateMe` action's code:

```
export const updateMe = state => ({
  type: "UPDATED_ME",
  payload: state
});
```

And this is the `me` reducer's code:

```
export default function(state = "NOT_AUTHENTICATED", action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATED_ME":
      return action.payload;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Also here's how I'm combining the reducers:

```
import me from "./me";
...
import { combineReducers } from "redux";

const reducers = combineReducers({
  me,
  ...
});

export default reducers;
```

Comment: Reducers are functions that update the application state when an action is triggered. In your code I see this.props being used so I think your code is from a component not a reducer. Are you trying to update your state from a component? If you can give us a bit more context about your code please.

Comment: @DiegoTArg Yeah, the code above is from a component. I'm trying to, once I call the updateUploadedFiles function from my component (let's call it `ComponentA`) it should update the reducer `me` and update `ComponentA`'s props

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how redux works.

In order to update **any** part of your Redux store you **must** *dispatch* an action in order to let Redux "know" that the store changed and update any dependent component.

You state object must be **immutable**.

Comment: I'm actually dispatching the action below here's how I'm doing it: `function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(
    {
      updatePath,
      updateMe,
      updateUploads
    },
    dispatch
  );
}`

Comment: I'm using bindActionCreators (which has dispatch in it) inside of mapDispatchToProps

Comment: Oh sorry, I read too fast. Can you see the action dispatched?

Comment: Can you provide action creator, reducer and component code?

Comment: In your question you say when you update your reducer the component doesn't update. So I guess the reducer is updated but your component's props are not. Are you mapping your state to your props the same way you are mapping the dispatch to your props? If not, I think that can be your issue.

Comment: @Jalil I've updated the question to include those two parts :)

Comment: @DiegoTArg I've updated the question's code, you can check it out :)

Comment: Is the `console.log` inside `updateUploadedFiles` working ?

Can you see the action dispatched ? Is your store updated ? (use Redux devtools : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/redux-devtools/lmhkpmbekcpmknklioeibfkpmmfibljd)

Comment: Yeah I can see it dispatched in redux-devtools but it's not updating my component at all

Comment: @Emad Salah, thanks ! It will also be really helpful if we can see the connection between your component and the store, list of props of your component and which one of them is not being updated.

Comment: Can you try having `{ pure: false }` as 4th argument of react-redux's `connect`?

Comment: Can you check if your `mapStateToProps` is called?

Comment: @Emad Salah, how does your combineReducers invocation look like?

Comment: @Jalil I've updated the post to contain more of the component's code

Comment: @Emad Salah, have you tried replacing the default string value from the reducer function ("NOT_AUTHENTICATED") with an object with the desired  structure? like for instance an object containing an empty folders array (and any other props you would need). I am not sure if this will help but that is the part that looks strange to me in the code you shared. I hope this helps you.

Comment: I guess that was a problem either with react-modal (which was a plugin that I was using in that part of code) or it was redux not re-rendering the component

Comment: Anyways, I will mark this answer as the solution since it helped me solve other issues in my code

Comment: I'm sorry you did not spot the exact cause... We are using react-modal and react-redux without difficulty so I think maybe you just had some mistyped part somewhere...